# How can you use modprobe nandsim for two chips?

Tags: flash

I have a board that uses two nand chips with data that appears to be interleaved byte-by-byte. I have manually desoldered the chips and dumped them with their respective spare areas to two files. I am trying to pull off data without having to worry about bad blocks or the order they occur on the chips. I am thinking I can do that using `modprobe nandsim` passing in the chip IDs and writing the images to them, but I can't figure out how (or if it is possible) to use nandsim with two chips that appear as one device.